# How to get Group in Azure AD in Pulumi?

Tags: azure-active-directory, infrastructure-as-code, pulumi

I'm trying to get a group in the Azure AD.

```cs
var group = Output.Create(
    GetGroup.InvokeAsync(
        new GetGroupArgs
        {
            Name = "Administrators"
        }));
```

```bsh
PS C:\dev\___> pulumi preview
Previewing update (dev):
     Type                 Name          Plan     Info
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack  Frontend-dev           1 error

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (Frontend-dev):
    error: Running program 'C:\dev\___\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Frontend.dll' failed with an unhandled exception:
    Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unknown, Detail="invocation of azuread:index/getGroup:getGroup returned an error: Error building AzureAD Client: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).

    To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
    auth method - instructions for which can be found here:

    Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.")
       at Pulumi.GrpcMonitor.InvokeAsync(InvokeRequest request)
       at Pulumi.Deployment.InvokeAsync[T](String token, InvokeArgs args, InvokeOptions options, Boolean convertResult)
       at Pulumi.Output`1.ApplyHelperAsync[U](Task`1 dataTask, Func`2 func)
       at Pulumi.Output`1.Pulumi.IOutput.GetDataAsync()
       at Pulumi.Serialization.Serializer.SerializeAsync(String ctx, Object prop)
       at Pulumi.Deployment.SerializeFilteredPropertiesAsync(String label, IDictionary`2 args, Predicate`1 acceptKey)
       at Pulumi.Deployment.SerializeAllPropertiesAsync(String label, IDictionary`2 args)
       at Pulumi.Deployment.RegisterResourceOutputsAsync(Resource resource, Output`1 outputs)
       at Pulumi.Deployment.Runner.WhileRunningAsync()
```

The `Pulumi.dev.yaml` contains the service principal credentials.

I followed the instructions to [create a service principal](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html) and [configure it with the appropriate permissions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/guides/service_principal_configuration.html).

The error message talks about some instructions:

> To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'
>       auth method - instructions for which can be found here: <- No link

Can anyone help me find those instructions so that I can sort out what I may have missed?

Comment: Could you please open an issue in https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azuread/ ?

Comment: Done. (Making up spaces to make SO happy)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the documentation, we're asked to put the credentials in the `Pulumi.<stack>.yml` via `pulumi config set azure:*` commands which led me to believe that that should be enough.

The thing is `Pulumi.Azure` will look for the settings in the `azure` namespace but `Pulumi.AzureAD` will look for the same settings in the `azuread` namespace.

So we not only need this:

```bsh
pulumi config set azure:clientId "00000000000000000000000"
pulumi config set azure:clientSecret "00000000000000000000000" --secret
pulumi config set azure:tenantId "00000000000000000000000"
pulumi config set azure:subscriptionId "00000000000000000000000"
```

But we also need run the below:

```bsh
pulumi config set azuread:clientId "00000000000000000000000"
pulumi config set azuread:clientSecret "00000000000000000000000" --secret
pulumi config set azuread:tenantId "00000000000000000000000"
pulumi config set azuread:subscriptionId "00000000000000000000000"
```

Which will get us a `Pulumi.<stack>.yml` similar to this:

```
config:
  azure:clientId: 00000000000000000000000
  azure:clientSecret:
    secure: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000XqZFM=
  azure:location: WestEurope
  azure:subscriptionId: 00000000000000000000000
  azure:tenantId: 00000000000000000000000
  azuread:clientId: 00000000000000000000000
  azuread:clientSecret:
    secure: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000l3xbaY=
  azuread:subscriptionId: 00000000000000000000000
  azuread:tenantId: 00000000000000000000000
```

Alternatively, you may also specify environment variables in powershell:

```bsh
$env:ARM_CLIENT_ID="0000000000000000000000000"
$env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="0000000000000000000000000"
$env:ARM_TENANT_ID="0000000000000000000000000"
$env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="0000000000000000000000000"
```

After doing that, my Pulumi stack was able to retrieve the Azure AD group object id successfully.

There's [github issue resolved](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azuread/issues/82).